# System.Drawing.Image from ImageSource in Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

My question is very similar to this one: [wpf image resources and changing image in wpf control at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940592/wpf-image-resources-and-changing-image-in-wpf-control-at-runtime#), but with a slight twist.

Here is my ResourceDictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ImageSource x:Key="DisconnectedIcon">Images/disconnect.png</ImageSource>
<ImageSource x:Key="Synced">Images/tick.png</ImageSource>
<ImageSource x:Key="NotSynced">Images/x.png</ImageSource>
```

As for the C# code behind, I am able to load the ImageSource from the resources with the following. In which, I am able to see the metadata and the image name, but can't figure out how to get it into a System.Drawings.Image.

```
var imageSource = (ImageSource)Application.Current.FindResource("Synced");

System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromFile(???)
```

The reason I am trying to convert it to a System.Drawing.Image is to send it to a printer.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap

Answer (score -1):

In WPF, every UI element extends the [`Visual` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which *Provides rendering support in WPF*. There is also a [`RenderTargetBitmap` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) that has a [`Render` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render.aspx) that takes a `Visual` object as an input parameter. So you could set your `ImageSource` as the `Source` property of an `Image` and simply render the `Image` to a `Bitmap` image:

```
Image yourImageObject = new Image();
yourImageObject.Source = yourImageSource;

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = 
    new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(yourImageObject);

// Save to .png file
PngBitmapEncoder pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();    
pngBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));    
using (Stream stream = File.Create(filepath))    
{    
    pngBitmapEncoder.Save(stream);    
}
```

As this is well documented on the internet, I won't bother to repeat the whole story here. To find out the full story, please see the [How to Render Bitmap or to Print a Visual in WPF](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/how-to-render-bitmap-or-to-print-visual.html) page from the Dot NET Tricks website, which will also help you with your printing requirement.

Comment: `var yourImageObject = System.Drawing.Image();` is not possible. You probably use another Image class instead

Comment: You are correct. This question relates to WPF, so the image class that is used by WPF is System.Windows.Controls.Image, not System.Drawing.Image. The question author's _real_ intention was to print the image from the `ImageSource`. I showed him how to do what he wanted the WPF way, as that is what he was working with. His title was just misleading, that's all.